# SQL - is Count still fast with nested queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

Supposed I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT message.mid
FROM message
WHERE message.mid <= 100
```

From what I know, if the query is changed to the following, it will execute much faster because the columns are not expanded.

```
SELECT COUNT(message.mid)
FROM message
WHERE message.mid <= 100
```

But would the following query have the same benefit? Would it still be as fast?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT message.mid,
           message.something,
           message.something2,
           message.something3,
    FROM message
    WHERE message.mid <= 100
) AS A
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a subquery if it's not needed? if there is a index `message(mid)` i assume the normal non subquery version is faster because the query will run on a covering index.

Comment: With MySQL versions before 5.7, with that third query, the inline view will cause a "derived table" to be materialized as an intermediate temporary table. Once that is done, then the outer query will run against that temporary table. In MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, the optimizer is improved, so that the inline view query can be merged into the outer block.  If the use case calls for just a count of rows, then use a query with COUNT() aggregate. If the use case calls for detail rows, use a query that returns only the columns that are needed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The question doesn't explain it, but I have a situation where I need to use a subquery.

Comment: @spencer7593 I didn't know about the optimization in 5.7 and 8.0 Thanks :) that helps

Comment: "I didn't know about the optimization in 5.7 and 8.0" you can read the docs here by the way https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

Comment: Is `mid` indexed? Is it the primary key?

Comment: @Schwern `mid` is the primary key, may or may not be indexed. But there might be multiple columns in the inner query. Let me update the question.
Edit: edited

Comment: If you breathe on the query, it may run slower or faster.  You mentioned that the subquery is required.  So I put it to you that you breathed on the query by removing the _reason_ for needing a subquery.  That is, my Answer, and any other Answers have not necessarily addressed you _real_ question.  (My Answer listed 6 ways one might 'breathe' on the query.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` says to count the rows.

`COUNT(x)` says to count the rows where `x IS NOT NULL`.  So a tiny bit slower, and possibly a different answer.

`SELECT mid` (versus `SELECT COUNT(...)`) -- slower and bulkier.  It is returning all the value of `mid`, not just a single number.

`SELECT COUNT(..) FROM ( SELECT ... )` -- Much slower (in older MySQL versions) because it must generate a temp table with the result of the subquery.  Also, `COUNT` is gathering just a simple number; the subquery is gathering lots of rows.

If `mid` is indexed (that includes the `PRIMARY KEY`, then `WHERE mid <= 100` is a "range" scan of the index (or table).  That is, it touches only some of the rows.

If `mid` is not indexed, then the entire table will be scanned -- hence slower.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer that I needed. Thank you!

Comment: *"Much slower because it must generate a temp table*" this is not correct for simple cases like this. MySQL can merge the subquery into the outer block making `select count(*) from ( select ... )` equivalent to `select count(*) ...`. No temp table required. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

Comment: @Schwern - True; the Optimizer, in _recent_ versions, can do such for some queries.  (I modified my statement.)

Answer (score 2):

[We can ask MySQL what it will do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html). This is 5.7.

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (     SELECT message.mid     FROM message     WHERE message.mid <= 100 
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | message | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  100 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


mysql> explain SELECT count(message.mid)     FROM message     WHERE message.mid <= 100;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | message | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  100 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Looks to be the same. MySQL has optimized away the subquery.

Here's an example of what we'd see when MySQL does not optimize away the subquery.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM (     SELECT message.mid     FROM message where mid < 100 group by mid) m;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   99 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | message    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   99 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

---

["Optimizing Derived Tables and View References"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html) has examples of how this optimization works.

> Example 1:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM t1) AS derived_t1;
> ```
>
> With merging, that query is executed similar to:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1;
> ```

That page outlines many other optimization tricks MySQL uses to make subqueries efficient.